# Classification of multiple images at once with exclusive classes in keras

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, classification

I have a set of 4 images that each have 1 of 6 classes. Each class can only be present in the set once. The model is trained to detect the viewing direction of objects (front, back, side, top, etc.) by looking at the entire set of images (in each input channel).
This works okay, but what can sometimes happen is the following:

The network classifies a view (lets say the front view) correctly as the front with a probability of 90%. It then looks at the back view and isnt really sure, so it classifies the back view as 52% front view and 48% back view. How can I "tell" the network that once a picture has been classified the other pictures cannot be that class?

The groundtruth for a set of 4 images might look like this:

```
[[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

And this is how a correct prediction looks like:

```
[[0.  0.  0.9 0.1 0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0. ]
 [0.8 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.2]
 [0.  0.9 0.  0.  0.1 0. ]]
```

These are the final layers of my network currently:

```
    outputs = keras.layers.Flatten()(conv)
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(num_classes*4)(outputs)
    outputs = keras.layers.Reshape((4, num_classes))(outputs)
    outputs = keras.layers.Activation('softmax')(outputs)
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Thank you!

Comment: My intuition is that your model might be fine, and that this error is a failure of training; a well-trained model should be able to incorporate conditionality. If you'd like to give the model a nudge, maybe add a term to the loss function like sum(r_i*r_j for i in 1:4, j in 1:4)? I'm not sure this would be best practice though

Comment: How could a training fail cause this? I confirmed that my one hot vectors are correct. Is there anything else?

Comment: Even if the training improves performance a good bit, you could still be stuck in a local minimum that doesn't obtain the best possible performance. This would would mean that your model is a bit too small; your hyper-parameter suite is sub-optimal; or your train data set doesn't cover enough of the latent data space.  I'm not sure that this is the case with your model, but I have a hunch that it may be. A powerful model should be able to largely pick up the relationship that you want to encode. If you'd like I could look at your code and see if the above is the case

Comment: I took a closer look at my data and I found quite a few faulty samples. I think I need to spend some time looking through my 3000 samples... If that doesnt fix it I will comment here again. Thank you for your help so far!